# Can not get RestTemplate to work properly. Ends up in 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: spring, http, rest, resttemplate, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to use Spring's RestTemplate to implement a payment provider into a project I'm working on. The XML being returned from the payment provider is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0031</bank_id>
        <bank_name>ABN AMRO</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0761</bank_id>
        <bank_name>ASN Bank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0091</bank_id>
        <bank_name>Friesland Bank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0721</bank_id>
        <bank_name>ING</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0021</bank_id>
        <bank_name>Rabobank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0771</bank_id>
        <bank_name>RegioBank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0751</bank_id>
        <bank_name>SNS Bank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0511</bank_id>
        <bank_name>Triodos Bank</bank_name>
    </bank>
    <bank>
        <bank_id>0161</bank_id>
        <bank_name>van Lanschot</bank_name>
    </bank>
<message>This is the current list of banks and their ID's that currently support iDEAL-payments</message>
</response>
```

The classes I created for this XML are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
public class ResponseBanks {

    private List<Bank> banks;
    private String message;

    public void setBanks(List<Bank> banks) {
        this.banks = banks;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="bank")
    public List<Bank> getBanks() {
        return banks;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="bank")
public class Bank {

    private String bank_id;
    private String bank_name;

    @XmlElement(name="bank_id")
    public String getBank_id() {
        return bank_id;
    }

    public void setBank_id(String bank_id) {
        this.bank_id = bank_id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="bank_name")
    public String getBank_name() {
        return bank_name;
    }

    public void setBank_name(String bank_name) {
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
    }
}
```

If I simply request the xml as a string and unmarshall them myself, it works:

```
String banksAsString = restTemplate.getForObject("https://secure.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=banklist", String.class);

        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseBanks.class);
            Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            ResponseBanks banks = (ResponseBanks) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(banksAsString));
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, if I do this:

```
ResponseBanks banksAsObject = restTemplate.getForObject("https://secure.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=banklist", ResponseBanks.class);
```

or

```
Source banksAsSource = restTemplate.getForObject("https://secure.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=banklist", Source.class);
```

it ends up in 406 Not Acceptable.

My beanconfiguration for restTemplate (which is @Autowired in the controller) looks like this:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">

        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
                    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>nl.mollie.api.ResponseBanks</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Does anybody have a clue what is causing this and how to fix it? The URL in the code above is publically accesible so you could try this code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`406 Not Acceptable` looks like problem with MIME-Types/content negotiation.

Web Service you try to communicate with doesn't send proper `Content-type`.
If this web service is implemented by you or your colleagues do you have `@Produces("application/xml")` annotation on your JAX-RS web-service method?

More here: https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-request-and-response-entities.html

Comment: This webservice is not implemented by ourselves. It is a 3rd party payment provider in the Netherlands, and not a small one at that. When I use the URL in a browser it returns "text/xml" so I recon that that part is not where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer as don't have enough reputation score to comment.

@Maciej, the link you posted above is not working. Do you have this content anywhere else available? 
 Please try to put key contents from the link while posting links.

Answer (score 0):

For you to use `Content-type` as `application/xml`, you need to configure the following message converter:

```
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
}

private MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml();
    builder.indentOutput(true);
    return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
}
```

and add this to your `pom.xml` file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-dataformat-xml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```